# Change button label based on condition as well as click in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying a list of users with 2 buttons being rendered for Start and End using **ng-repeat** code:

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="patient in patients" >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"  ng-click="chatNow(patient.id);" >{{patient.firstname}} {{patient.lastname}}</a> &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="chatNow(patient.id);">{{btnLabel}}</button> &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="endVideo(patient.appointmentId);">End Consultation</button>
                </div> <!-- list-group ends -->
```

This list is refreshed every **30 seconds** using `$http.get`.

`btnLabel` is set in `Controller` using:

```
var t = $scope;
t.btnLabel = 'Start Consultation';
```

Now this is changed when `chatNow` is called on `ng-click`

```
    t.chatNow = function(jobId) {
  t.btnLabel = 'In Progress'; 
 };
```

However, I want the Label to be changed if one other property `chatStatus` changes as well like

```
{{patient.chatStatus == 22 ? 'Start Consultation':'In Progress'}}
```

The problem is that I am not able to combine both of these together, such that

> the label changes on click as well as when there is a change in
>   chatStatus

. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Any more pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.$watch('chatStatus', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue != oldValue && newValue == 22) {
        $scope.btnLabel = 'Start Consultation';
    }
});
```

Here's an update now that I've had a chance to do a closer review.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="patient in patients">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"  ng-click="chatNow(patient.id);" >{{patient.firstname}} {{patient.lastname}}</a> &nbsp;
    <button ng-init="btnLabel[$index]='Start Consultation'" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="chatNow(patient.id);">{{btnLabel[$index]}}</button> &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="endVideo(patient.appointmentId);">End Consultation</button>
  </div> <!-- list-group ends -->
  <button ng-click="thirtySecondRefresh(1)">30 Second Refresh</button>
</body>
```

AngularJS/JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.btnLabel = [];
  $scope.patients = [
    {id: 21, firstname: 'Tim', lastname: 'Harker', chatStatus: 22},
    {id: 17, firstname: 'Satya', lastname: 'Unknown', chatStatus: 22},
    {id: 75, firstname: 'Stack', lastname: 'Overflow', chatStatus: 22}
  ];
  $scope.chatNow = function(id) {
    $scope.btnLabel[$scope.patients.indexOf($scope.patients.find(x => x.id == id))] = 'In Progress';
  };
  $scope.$watch('patients', function (newValues, oldValues) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newValues.length; i++) {
      if (newValues[i].chatStatus != 22) {
        $scope.btnLabel[i] = 'In Progress';
      }
    }
  }, true);
  $scope.thirtySecondRefresh = function(id) {
    $scope.patients[id].chatStatus = 20; // other than 22
  };
});
```

And here's a link to the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bd6UhU4RwDiYKGhEhR0n?p=preview

I hope it helps!

Comment: Do you get an error?  Can you provide more information as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: let me try pulling a plunker for you

Comment: Got ya, it's because it's "patient".chatStatus, in an array.  If I get a chance later today I'll modify your working JSFiddle.  It should be very do-able!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim . I appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks a ton @Tim. I modified my solution based upon your code and it is working like a charm. Thanks again!!

Comment: No worries.  The trick is watching the array of objects for a property change (deep watch) with the 'true' in $watch.

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/U4lVEhPZb5GPEc1wefdd?p=preview

Do required validations as per your need

```
  $scope.clickdata = function($event){
   $event.target.innerHTML = "In Progress"
 }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot Sharmila. I managed to fix  it using @Tim's solution above. Regards

Comment: Welcome satya.. Just another way of doing :)